# Do I have to include libraries in my main.cpp if it includes a header file whose .cpp has those libraries included?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am approaching c++ programming, and I am making a main.cpp that includes a header file (let's call it functions.h). Now, if in the functions.cpp I am including some libraries, do I have to include them again in the main.cpp or it's not necessary?

I know that when I include a header file, I automatically include all the libraries that the header is including. But does this happens also with its .cpp file?

Comment: "including libraries" isn't a super common or descriptive terminology. you include headers, and you link library binaries.

Comment: Does functions.cpp file #include functions.h?

Comment: ***I automatically include all the libraries that the header is including.*** The header usually has declarations that promise that the definition of functions and or variables will come somewhere else. And that somewhere else the output of compiling a cpp file or files or linking a library or libraries.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, I have the functions.h, the functions.cpp that  #include "functions.h" (and other libraries) and the main.cpp which #include "functions.h"

Comment: The compiler will typically compile `functions.cpp` and `main.cpp` in to individual object files and feed the object files to your linker which produces the executable from the object files.

Comment: @drescherjm so is it correct to say that I don't need to put #include<stdlib.h> in the main.cpp if I already included it in the functions.cpp?

Comment: cpp source files are compiled completely separate of each other often these days compiled separate instances of your compiler  in parallel so if any part of main needs `stdlib.h` then you must include it in `main.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you might want to insert a `#include` directive into any `.cpp` or `.h` file is because you know there is code later on in that same file that won't compile unless the compiler has first parsed the declarations present inside the file that you `#include`-d.

For example, if you know that `main.cpp` is going to call `std::cout << "Hello"`, then you'll want to `#include <iostream>` at the top of `main.cpp` so that the compiler won't error out with an `undeclared identifier 'std::cout'` error when it reaches that line of code in `main.cpp`.

Since each `.cpp` file is compiled separately, you need to make sure that the proper `#include` directives are present in each .cpp file that needs them.  For example, if there is *also* code in your `functions.cpp` file  that references `std::cout`, then your `functions.cpp` file should *also* have a `#include <iostream>` at its top.

Complicating things a little bit is the issue of which include-directives to insert at the top of your own `.h` files.  For example, if your `functions.h` file has a declaration like this:

```
void DoSomethingWithAFooObject(Foo & s);
```

... then you'll want to put *something* near the top of `functions.h` so that when the compiler encounters that declaration, it won't error out because it doesn't know what a `Foo` is.  Assuming you haven't declared `class Foo {...}` directly inside this same header file, then the obvious thing to put at the top of `functions.h` is e.g. `#include "Foo.h"` (or whatever header file you have where `class Foo {...}` is declared), since that will pull in the definition the compiler needs.  A side effect of that will be that any `.cpp` files that `#include` your `functions.h` will now be implicitly also `#include`-ing `Foo.h` as a side effect; whether you want to rely on that indirect inclusion or keep the `#includes` in both your `.h` and your `.cpp` files is up to you -- there are arguments for and against it.

Note that in some cases you can avoid having to put a `#include` in your header file by putting a forward-declaration there instead, e.g.:

```
// in functions.h

class Foo;  // forward declaration -- tells the compiler that a class named Foo exists

void PrintToStream(Foo & s);
```

This will compile, because in order to parse the function declaration, the compiler only needs to know that a class named `Foo` *exists*, it doesn't need to know anything about how it works, and moreover it will compile faster than if the compiler had to read in and parse the whole `Foo.h` header file.  However, any code that actually *uses* `Foo` objects (as opposed to just mentioning the name `Foo`) will still need to do the full `#include "Foo.h"`.  In particular, calling methods on an object, declaring an object, or doing pointer math with an object all require knowing the object's size, which a forward-declaration does not provide.

Comment: thanks a lot, your explanation was really exhaustive and useful.